# Как сделать так чтобы по клику на кнопку выведите число 1, а по двойному клику - число 2?

Tags: javascript

**Как сделать так чтобы по клику на кнопку выведите число 1, а по двойному клику - число 2?**

Comment: https://habr.com/ru/sandbox/30928/

Comment: Не работает!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я не совсем понял куда выводить, так что выводил на туже кнопку.

Пример на чисто JS как я понял нужен:

```js
const btn = document.getElementById('btn');

btn.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
  btn.innerHTML = 1;
});

btn.addEventListener('dblclick', function (e) {
  btn.innerHTML = 2;
});
```

```html
<button id="btn">click me</button>
```

Comment: если поставите console.log, то получите и 1, и 2

Comment: Спасибо!!!!!!!!!!!